# place gtag event snippet head Gatsby/React site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gtag.js, react-helmet

I am having issues placing an event snippet in  on my thank you-page. The site is built in GatsbyJS. My thought was placing the event snippet in  using React helmet but can't seem to figure out how to do it correctly. I've tried all different things but neither seems to work:

```
<Helmet>
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-MYID'});
</script>
</Helmet>
```

```
<Helmet>
<script
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-MYID'});
/>
</Helmet>
```

```
<Helmet>
<script>
{`
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-MYID'});
`}
</script>
</Helmet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag) documentation to add custom events in server-side rendering (SSR):

```
typeof window !== "undefined" && window.gtag("event", "click", { ...data })
```

You need to access to `window` object first. Of course, after checking if it's available the request time as the [debugging HTML in Gatsby shows](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging-html-builds/).

Of course, this assumes that you have properly installed the plugin in your `gatsby-config.js`. Ideal customization should look like:

```
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        // You can add multiple tracking ids and a pageview event will be fired for all of them.
        trackingIds: [
          "GA-TRACKING_ID", // Google Analytics / GA
          "AW-CONVERSION_ID", // Google Ads / Adwords / AW
          "DC-FLOODIGHT_ID", // Marketing Platform advertising products (Display & Video 360, Search Ads 360, and Campaign Manager)
        ],
        // This object gets passed directly to the gtag config command
        // This config will be shared across all trackingIds
        gtagConfig: {
          optimize_id: "OPT_CONTAINER_ID",
          anonymize_ip: true,
          cookie_expires: 0,
        },
        // This object is used for configuration specific to this plugin
        pluginConfig: {
          // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
          head: false,
          // Setting this parameter is also optional
          respectDNT: true,
          // Avoids sending pageview hits from custom paths
          exclude: ["/preview/**", "/do-not-track/me/too/"],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thank a lot, Ferran! Still not quite sure where to add window object tho. Should it be added in a React helmet on my thank you page?

Comment: Just call it as a function when you need to trigger or to update your analytics. In your thank you page should be triggered in a `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` hook.

Comment: hmm... it gives me error: "React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "landingPage" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks"

Comment: Yes! https://codeshare.io/5enlbL - gatsby-plugin-google-gtag have been installed and working.

Comment: the solution was quite simple: Had to capitalize the first letter of landingPage (the name of the component) which solved things!

Comment: Yes, components must start with capital letters.